# Binary Search-accessing the middle element drawback

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, data-structures, binary-search

I am studying from my course book on Data Structures by Seymour Lipschutz and I have come across a point I don’t fully understand..

> Binary Search Algorithm assumes that one has direct access to middle element in the list. This means that the list must be stored in some typeof linear array.

I read this and also recognised that in Python you can have access to the middle element at all times. Then the book goes onto say:

> Unfortunately, inserting an element in an array requires elements to be moved down the list, and deleting an element from an array requires element to be moved up the list.

How is this a Drawback ?
Won’t we still be able to access the middle element by dividing the length of array by 2?

Comment: The book does not look so good from those quotes, for instance binary search also works on monotonic functions not only lists, and why would you need to insert/delete something during binary search? you just keep variables for left/right borders and change those so insert/delete is not a drawback

Comment: Deleting and Inserting won’t be during search but to update the records...

Comment: In that case update will take `O(n)` and search `O(log n)` if using array and `O(1)` and `O(n)` if using linked list if there are many updates of course this is slow, using some tree structures we can achieve both update/search in `O(log n)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case where the array will not be modified, the cost of insertion and deletion are not relevant.

However, if an array is to be used to maintain a sorted set of non-fixed items, then insertion and deletion costs are relevant. In this case, binary search can be used to find items (possibly for deletion) and/or find where new items should be inserted. The drawback is that insertion and deletion require movement of other elements.

Python's [bisect](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/bisect.html) module provides binary search functionality that can be used for locating insertion points for maintaining sorted order. The drawback mentioned applies.

In some cases, a [binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) may be a preferable alternative to a sorted array for maintaining a sorted set of non-fixed items.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that author compares array-like structures  and **linked** list

The first (array, Python and Java list, C++ vector) allows fast and simple access to any element by index, but appending, inserting or deletion might cause memory redistribution.

For the second we cannot address i-th element directly, we need to traverse list from the beginning, but when we have element -  we can insert or delete quickly.